# How to get font size in list view and set bigger for a specific item programmatically

Tags: android, listview, font-size

The size of a textview in a listview is 19SP. I want to set the first position item's font size bigger, e.g. 21SP. How can I do it programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just set the size at runtime for all cases cause getting font size from textview which is inside listview is something i won't prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the `getView` method from your adapter to suit your needs.

The method `getView` as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) provides you with the position of the item in the dataset you are trying to display.

All you need to do is customize the inflated view based on the position like you are asking

```
   getView(int position, 
                View convertView, 
                ViewGroup parent){
    //inflate the view
   View v =  LayoutInflator.from(parent).inflate(R.layout.your_layout,parent,false);   
   TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_txt);
   if(position == 0){
   txt.setTextSize(//get the dimen from resources);
   }
   return v;    
  }
```

Comment: I'm doing this way, just want to know how to set text size. After some research, I know how to code. Thanks anyway.